# How can I calculate the most common bird flight direction from multiple angles in a circle?

Tags: r, math, geometry

I am calculating the most common flight path of birds over a given area (airport). I know their position (distance from me) and their flight angle. I am situated at a particular point and birds are flying around me. I make the assumption that all the birds are flying in a straight line.

How can I know what is the most common flight path over the area?

Example of flight angles:

```
direction <- c(35, 70, 300, 260, 340, 130, 240, 40, 190, 190, 150, 20)
```

I plotted their position given the distance and angle from me. Then I added their flight angle and a made up distance of their flight just to see the flight-path (1.5 km).

[image]

As you might see it is a bit chaotic but I would like to know roughly if birds are flying more frequently in some range of angles (20-30° range) or if it is all random.

Answer (score 2):

Would a simple count of data points per category be enough information? You can use "cut" to do this based on the categories that you define. E.g.

```
library(dplyr)
direction <- c(35, 70, 300, 260, 340, 130, 240, 40, 190, 190, 150, 20)
categoryBreaks <- c(0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,260,280,300,320,340,360)

catDirection <- data.frame(direction) %>%
  arrange(direction) %>%
  mutate(category = cut(direction, categoryBreaks))
```

And plotting this:

```
ggplot(catDirection) +
  geom_bar(aes(category)) +
  xlab("Angle of Flight") +
  ylab("Count of birds") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Do you need something more complex?

Comment: Thank you! This is very good to visualize my data. I can see clear patterns though they might not be perfect. 

I think the data is not good enough to be able to find out the bird traffic at a particular parts of the airport. That would require radar data I guess. I can find out how many birds use the whole area with the package distance but visualizing it is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. For example, you can compare the frequencies: flights within 20-30 range vs other ranges. Or maybe you can also express all flights as distance from that range and plot it or look for correlation.